# CSS grid is being ignored

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

Hi I'm still relatively new to HTML and CSS at just a few weeks of practice and I had some success using grids on previous projects but am now stuck as it appears when I try to use grid: display; it is currently being ignored.

```css
#container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "navbar content";
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  justify-content: center;
}
#main-doc{
 
}
#main-title{
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: gray;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
}
#navtitle{
  grid-area: navbar;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main id="main-doc">
    <div id="container">
    <h1 id="main-title">main doc</h1>
    <nav id="navtitle">Title</nav>
    </div>
  </main>
  

</body>
```

Comment: Sorry that was a copying error, the grid is still ignored for me

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: a navbar that takes up 1 third of the page on  the left side, with the content taking up the other 2 thirds

Comment: Actually I think I've managed to fix it, but if anyone would like to review it and let me know if it's correct I would be really greatfull

Answer (score 0):

By removing the grid-column-start and grid-column-end from the `#main-title`, you can achieve the desired result:

```css
#container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "navbar content";
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  justify-content: center;
}
#main-title{
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: gray;
}
#navtitle{
  grid-area: navbar;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main id="main-doc">
    <div id="container">
      <h1 id="main-title">main doc</h1>
      <nav id="navtitle">Title</nav>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply I appreciate it I have since removed them thanks.